# If condition in Google sheet formula is true but recognized as false

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I have this Google Sheet:

[image]

I have this formula in in B2:

```
=IF(A2-A1=0.1, "OK", "ERROR")
```

And basically the same formula in B6:

```
=IF(A6-A5=0.1, "OK", "ERROR")
```

For a sanity check, these are the formulas in A3 and A7:

```
=A2-A1
=A6-A5
```

Is there any logical reason why I get ERROR in B2 and OK in B6?  Or is this a bizarre Google Sheets bug?

Here is [the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jutOzNblGCEy4unDyQafTA1BGo5d_MFdvxOChBgOqJ8/edit?usp=sharing) if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: This is very weird. Even if you change the formula to `=IF(A3=0.1, "OK", "ERROR")` the error persists. And in fact checking 1 and 1.1, 2 and 2.1, and 3 and 3.1 all work, while 4 and 4.1 onward fail.

Comment: Interesting. If you try checking for equality against `A3` instead of the literal `0.1`, the formula works. I wonder if it's some odd type checking bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Floating Point Error](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and it's not unique to Google Sheets. Use `ROUND` with 2 decimal precision as a workaround:

```
=IF(ROUND(A2-A1,2)=0.1,"OK","ERROR")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with that, but I'm  shocked that Google wouldn't do some internal rounding to make it work with simple calculations.  Especially, since numbers are presented with fixed precision.

Comment: So agree! Excel uses snap-to-zero to avoid these constant floating point calc errors, so you don't have the wrap EVERYTHING in Round() first. Snap-To-Zero should be a user option in Sheets!